# d3.js: swap between topojson maps on mouseclick?

Tags: function, dictionary, d3.js, mouseclick-event, geojson

I am making a topojson map with d3.js. I have three data sets within one big topojson that draw different maps, and I would like to swap between the maps on mouseclick.

I thought I could achieve this by adding a function to the mouseclick event and put the result in the `.datum()` operator.

---

UPDATE: here is the working code, thanks Lars!

```
var mapPath = d3.geo.path().projection(mapProjection),
    jsondata,
    jsonobject,
    jsonobjectkeys,
    numberOfKeys,
    currentMap
    mapNumber;

d3.json("test.json", function(error, json){
      if (error) return console.warn(error);
      jsondata = json; //Store data in the variable "jsondata"
      jsonobject = json.objects;
      jsonobjectkeys = [];
      numberOfKeys = 0;

      //Get the maps(keys) from the jsonobject
      for(var k in jsonobject) jsonobjectkeys.push(k);

      //Find number of objects in jsondata
      for (objects in jsonobject){
        if((jsonobject).hasOwnProperty(objects)){
            numberOfKeys++;
        }
      }

mapNumber = jsonobjectkeys[0];

currentMap = eval("jsonobject." + (mapNumber));

//Map
var mapSVG = d3.select(".the_map")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", mapW)
                .attr("height", mapH);
    mapSVG.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.object(jsondata, currentMap))
            .attr("d", mapPath)
            .attr("width", mapW)
            .attr("height", mapH)
            .attr("class", "land");

//Timeline

//Create scale
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, (numberOfKeys-1)])
    .range([timelinePadding, timelineW - timelinePadding]);

//Axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(numberOfKeys-1);

var timeline = d3.select("#timeline")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", timelineW)
        .attr("height", timelineH);
    timeline.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + timelinePadding + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    timeline.selectAll("circle")
       .data(jsonobjectkeys)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("width", timelineW)
       .attr("height", timelineH)
       .attr("cx", function(d,i){return xScale(i);})
       .attr("cy", timelinePadding)
       .attr("r", 7)
       .attr("class", "events")
       .style("cursor", "hand")
       .on("click", function(d){
            redrawMap(d);
       });

 function redrawMap(i){
            currentMap = eval("jsonobject." + (i));
    //Update
    mapSVG.selectAll("path")
    .datum(topojson.object(jsondata, currentMap))
    .attr("d", mapPath);
}

});
```

---

Original, not working code:

```
var mapPath = d3.geo.path().projection(mapProjection),
    jsondata,
    jsonobject,
    jsonobjectkeys,
    numberOfKeys;


d3.json("test.json", function(error, json){
      if (error) return console.warn(error);
      jsondata = json; //Store data in the variable "jsondata"
      jsonobject = json.objects;
      jsonobjectkeys = [];
      numberOfKeys = 0;

      //Get the maps(keys) from the jsonobject
      for(var k in jsonobject) jsonobjectkeys.push(k);

      //Find number of objects in jsondata
      for (objects in jsonobject){
        if((jsonobject).hasOwnProperty(objects)){
            numberOfKeys++;
        }
      }

var mapNumber = jsonobjectkeys[0];

var currentMap = eval("jsonobject." + (mapNumber));

currentMapData(mapNumber);

//Map
var mapSVG = d3.select(".the_map")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", mapW)
                .attr("height", mapH);
    mapSVG.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.object(jsondata, currentMap))
            .attr("d", mapPath)
            .attr("width", mapW)
            .attr("height", mapH)
            .attr("class", "land");

//Timeline

//Create scale
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, (numberOfKeys-1)])
    .range([timelinePadding, timelineW - timelinePadding]);

//Axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(numberOfKeys-1);

var timeline = d3.select("#timeline")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", timelineW)
        .attr("height", timelineH);
    timeline.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + timelinePadding + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    timeline.selectAll("circle")
       .data(jsonobjectkeys)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("width", timelineW)
       .attr("height", timelineH)
       .attr("cx", function(d,i){return xScale(i);})
       .attr("cy", timelinePadding)
       .attr("r", 7)
       .attr("class", "events")
       .style("cursor", "hand")
       .on("click", function(d,i){
            currentMapData(i);
       });

 function currentMapData(i){
            mapNumber = jsonobjectkeys[i];
    console.log("showing this map: " + mapNumber);
    currentMap = eval("jsonobject." + (mapNumber));
    return currentMap;
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're binding the object keys as data, but expecting to receive an index in `currentMapData()`. So the error that you're seeing is caused by you attempting to use a key to index into an array. You can pass the index instead of the key by using the second argument of the `onclick` handler, i.e. replace

```
.on("click", function(d){
     currentMapData(d);
});
```

with

```
.on("click", function(d, i){
     currentMapData(i);
});
```

Comment: You're right! I updated the code, however, the map still doesn't change. Is there somewhere else I need to change to code so that the path is updated (I thought it would be enough to update the datum property)?

Comment: You need to redraw all the elements. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html) (and part 2) for more details.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to go about this, since .datum() does not compute enter and exit selections. How can I redraw without using .enter()?

Comment: The same thing applies except that your selection is implicit. So after updating the data, select the element and call the functions to redraw. It's more similar to the second part of the tutorial where existing elements are updated.

Comment: Here is what I ended up with (please correct me if there is a better way):

I replaced currentMapData() with the new function drawMap() where I put the entire mapSVG. Feels a bit cumbersome, but it works:
`function drawMap(i){ 
mapNumber = jsonobjectkeys[i]; currentMap = eval("jsonobject." + (mapNumber)); mapSVG.append("path").datum(topojson.object(jsondata, currentMap)).attr("d", mapPath).attr("width", mapW).attr("height", mapH).attr("class", "land");}`

Comment: Sounds like your method is better, but I'm still not sure how to do it. When you refer to the second part of the tutorial, you mean the "Creating Elemens" and "Destroying Elements", right?

Comment: By the second part I mean [this](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html). Your code looks reasonable, except that in subsequent calls you don't need to append the path, but would instead select it.

Comment: Aha, then everything makes sense. Thanks for your patience, Lars!